# Add content to transcluded content in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to add content to the transcluded html inside my directive. While it works visually, the console is giving me an error and I don't know how to fix it.

Here's a plunkr showing the issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/HQHRisu9QZZ0GHBdAEl4?p=preview

Line 39 of app.js is mainly what I'm trying to do and is causing the error:

```
children.prepend('<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>');
```

In the console output, there is this:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'nodeValue' of undefined
at Object.interpolateFnWatchAction [as fn] (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:6913:37)
at Scope.$digest (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:12447:29)
at Scope.$apply (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:12712:24)
at done (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:8315:45)
at completeRequest (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:8527:7)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:8466:11)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was. Posting the answer here in case it helps anyone.

**Original code:**

```
var tbody = transclude(function(clone) {
    var children = clone.children('tr');

    children.attr('ng-repeat', 'item in data');
    children.prepend('<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>');
});

$compile(tbody)($scope.$parent, function(clone) {
    $element.append(clone);
});
```

**Fixed code:**

Instead of modifying the html inside the transclude, I had to use jquery to add the html afterwards.

```
var tbody = transclude(function(clone) {
    var children = clone.children('tr');

    children.attr('ng-repeat', 'item in data');
}); 

$(tbody[1]).find('tr').prepend('<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>');  

$compile(tbody)($scope.$parent, function(clone) {
    $element.append(clone);
});
```